# Datagrid bound to CollectionView, Splitting a row into two

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have columns 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

First two are attributes, others hold data
I want to split each row into two and use labels as column headers

1,2,3,4,5

1,2,6,7,8

If I can do

```
 1
  2
   3 4 5
   6 7 8
```

That would be even better. But I don't know where to start

Comment: Algorithms + Data Structures = Programs. choose the data structure, which is convenient for the view, then transform your original data into that format (algorithm for that shouldn't be complex). when it is done, you get a working program

Comment: use grouping and style like here https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/grouping-in-datagrid-in-wpf/

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be use a expander with a horizontal stackpanel for Column1,
another expander with a horizontal stackpanel for Column2 and for columns 3 to 8 use a datagrid. All this contents are derived from the items control defined within a grid.
The data itself can be defined as a observable collection source, which can be updated based on the program needs.

```
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Datasource1}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
              <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel >
                </StackPanel>
              </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate>
                  <Expander Header="Header1"  >
                                <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel>                                       
                                            </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Datasource2}">
                      <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                          <StackPanel></StackPanel>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                      </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                      <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Expander Header="Header2">
                                <Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </Expander.HeaderTemplate>
                                <DataGrid  ItemsSource="{Binding Datasource3to8}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
                              <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test"
                                                    Width="Auto"
                                                    Binding="{Binding Datasource3}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test"
                                                    Width="Auto"
                                                    Binding="{Binding Datasource4}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test"
                                                    Width="Auto"
                                                    Binding="{Binding Datasource5}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test"
                                                    Width="Auto"
                                                    Binding="{Binding Datasource6}" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test"
                                                    Width="Auto"
                                                    Binding="{Binding Datasource7}" />
                              <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test"
                                                    Width="Auto"
                                                    Binding="{Binding Datasource8}" />
                              </DataGrid.Columns>
                             </DataGrid>
                          </Expander>
                        </DataTemplate>
                      </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
                  </Grid>
                </Expander>
              </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
          </ItemsControl>
```

Another option would be to use a heirarchial data grid.